# How to remove the multiple metacharacters from a File python3

Tags: python-3.x

How to remove the multiple metacharacters from a File python3 likewise if i want to remove double Quotes(`"`), single quote(`'`), plus operator(`+`),hyphen(`-`), equal sign(`=`) and comma(`,`).

For example for double quoted we can do as below..

```
    In [1]: import re

    In [2]: re.sub(r"\"", "", '"remove all "double quotes" from text"')
    Out[2]: 'remove all double quotes from text'

    In [3]: re.sub(r"(^\"|\"$)", "", '"remove all "only surrounding quotes" from text"')
    Out[3]: 'remove all "only surrounding quotes" from text'
```

Lets have an example like below where we have thousands of such lines into a file and we have to apply this on the same:

```
adding new entry "cn=hdl-binsun+ipHostNumber=192.1698.232.92,ou=hosts,ou=corp,ou=services,o=hdl.com"
```

Just simulating the above example, i came across the Below code which works as desired:

```
# replacer.py
import re
f = open('file.txt', mode='rt', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    new_str = re.sub(r'[+=",]', ' ', line)
    print(new_str)
    #new_str = re.sub(r'[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,%$]', ' ', line)
```

> I get the desired output as below

```
$ python replacer.py
adding new entry  cn hdl-binsun ipHostNumber 192.168.232.92 ou hosts ou corp ou services o hdl.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the replace function man

you dont even need to use re

```
a = "remove all \"double quotes\" from text".replace("\"", "")
```

or maybe here we go

```
def replacer(string, sth_to_remove):
   return string.replace(sth_to_remove, "")

a = replacer(a, "\"")
```

you can use a list like

```
not_needed = ['+', '-', '\"']

def replacer(string, sth_to_remove):
       if type(sth_to_remove) == list:
           for i in sth_to_remove:
               string = string.replace(i, "")
       else:
         string = string.replace(sth_to_remove, "")
       return string
a = replacer(a, not_needed)
```

Comment: Kostadin, thanks for your detailed input, i'll check that.